# EF Core defining "complex" relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm having a hard time defining the relations I want using EF Core(1 to many) .

E.G:

I am an entity of `Task` and `Employee` , each task is given by an employee and also is appointed to an employee . I've created the `Task` class as follow:

```
public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RequestedBy")]
    [Required]
    public int RequestedById { get; set; }
    [Required]

    [ForeignKey("TaskedTo")]
    public int TaskedToId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee RequestedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee TaskedTo { get; set; }
}
```

I think I've done it correctly, but I have a problem with my Employee class. Usually (When there's only one join) I would simply create virtual collection of `Task` Property in Employee .. but what am I supposed to do now ? Is this enough to set the relation or should I add virtual properties for these two tasks?

And another thing, when I have an owned entity, with 1-Many relation , is it enough to add the property in the owner entity, and do nothing in the owned one? Or do I have to specify the [Owned] Annotation?

Comment: Can you post your `Employee` entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have *two* one-to-many relationships between the same two entities. For the `Employee` class you would need two collections, one for each relationship. Additionally, you'll need to use the `InverseProperty` attribute to tell EF which foreign key goes with which collection:

```
public class Employee
{
    ...

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Task.RequestedBy))]
    public ICollection<Task> RequestedTasks { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Task.TaskedTo))]
    public ICollection<Task> AssignedTasks { get; set; }
}
```

You don't need `virtual`. That's to enable lazy-loading. For the lazy-loading functionality, EF creates a dynamic proxy class that inherits from your entity and overrides the getter on the navigation property. The `virtual` keyword is required in C# to allow a class member to be overridden.

Also, the `Owned` attribute is for value objects. It's a way of having a related class whose properties are literally mapped onto the same table or if given its own table, inherently tied to the entity that "owns" it, such that you access that data *through* the entity, not separately. Neither of which applies here.

Finally, you should reconsider the name `Task` for this class. .NET already has a `Task` class, and it's used very frequently. If you name your class `Task` as well, you'll be having to specify namespaces virtually every time you use either one, which is a pain.

Comment: A question regarding the owned entity. I wasn't talking about the example I gave. I meant for example : The `Task` has `Priority` , which is a value entity (an id and type) , so do I need to specify `Owned` in `Priority`? or a `Priority` property in `Task` in enough?

Comment: If `Priority` is a separate entity class, because you're wanting to manage an standard list of priorities, then that should be a reference (i.e. foreign key). If it's enough to just store the value, i.e. something like 1 or "High", then you can do it as a property. You might also consider using a enum for that instead.